# import - xpath or convert to .csv?

Tags: c#, xpath, csv, import

Im looking for some advice on how I should go about a solution. I have an import to write using c#. The data comes from an xml file containing ~30000 records each with ~10 nodes for differnet data. My initial thought would be to create a node list of records ids(one of the nodes is a unique id). Then loop through the node list and use xpath to get the rest of the data for the record. My other thought was to convert the xml file into .cvs format and read it that way. Before i dive head first into one or the other any advice, pros/cons or suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Personally, I would use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query the XML directly.

Transforming to CSV has its own pitfalls, if you don't adhere to the rules (quoting fields, line breaks within fields etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above poster that you want to use LINQ to XML if possible, however if you are on an older version of the framework you could use an XMLDocument and the SelectNodes/SelectSingleNode methods. If you do that however make sure you use a NamespaceManager or you won't return anything from your methods unless your XML has no namespaces etc.

That got me a bunch of times.